# How to easily add/remove cells from a Table (Shifting existent cells)

Tags: css, html, html-table, cell

I want a table to automatically align cells to be two per row, meaning that if a add/remove a cell, cells will shift to be two per row (with one on last row if total number of cells is odd).

Example:

```
<table>

<tr>
<td>old1</td> <td>old2</td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td>old3</td> <td>old4</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

To this:

```
<table>

<tr>
<td>NEW</td> <td>old1</td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td>old2</td> <td>old3</td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td>old4</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

> Notice the automatically added **row**.

Comment: For that you'd need to use JavaScript, or use something other than an HTML table to contain the contents to show, such as a list, with `<li>` child elements.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking or what the problem is.

Comment: are you trying to make it look like a blog? that you keep the first on top and the "old news" on the bottom?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll show you three ways to accomplish what you need,

- [css3](/questions/tagged/css3) Using `flex` (**modern** browsers only)
- [css](/questions/tagged/css) Using **`inline-table`** (problem with **cell height** but usable as *sort-of* fallback)
- [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) Using standard `<table>` **(All browsers!)**

### Using CSS3's FLEX

```css
.table{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.cell{
  width:50%;
  background:#ddd;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="cell">NEW</div>
  <div class="cell">OLD1</div>
  <div class="cell">OLD2</div>
  <div class="cell">OLD3<br>new line</div>
  <div class="cell">OLD4</div>
</div>
```

### Using `inline-table` (issue with cell height)

`display: table;`   for the parent element and
`display: inline-table` for the inner DIVs:

```css
.table{
  display:table;
}
.cell{
  display:inline-table;
  width:50%;     /* With percentage you simulate "how-many-per-Row" */
  background:#ddd;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="cell">NEW</div>
  <div class="cell">OLD1</div>
  <div class="cell">OLD2</div> <!-- Works but notice this cell height  -->
  <div class="cell">OLD3<br>new line</div> 
  <div class="cell">OLD4</div>
</div>
```

You could use the `inline-table` as a fallback for older browsers - it's not the exact same result but without JavaScript it's the best you could get.

<sub>Take a look in the specs about the `display` property: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display</sub>

---

### Using `<table>`, `<tr>` and `<td>` and JavaScript (jQuery)

If you want to stick to good 'ol `table` elements you can use "a bit" of jQuery.
In that case it's a bit more complicated (see code-comments):

```js
jQuery(function($){ // DOM is now ready

  var $table = $("table"); // Get your table
  var maxRowCells = 2;     // only 2-per-Row
  var counter = 0;         // just a dummy counter

  function prependNewCell(){

    var $newCell = $("<td/>", {html: "NEW"+(++counter)});

    // Is the last row full?
    if($table.find("tr:last td").length == maxRowCells){
      // If true, append a new TR to TABLE to shift TD's to
      $table.append( $("<tr/>") ); 
    }


    // Shift all last TD's to the next row:
    $table.find("tr:not(:last)").each(function(){
      var $tdLast = $(this).find("td").last();
      $(this).next("tr").prepend( $tdLast );
    });

    // Finally. Prepend the new TD element to the first TR
    $table.find("tr").first().prepend( $newCell );

  }

  $("button").on("click", prependNewCell);

});
```

```css
td{
  width:50%;
  background:#ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>ADD NEW CELL ON TOP</button>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>OLD1</td>
    <td>OLD2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>OLD3</td>
    <td>OLD4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @DaniSpringer Thought it would be obvious. `<br>` the line break is clearly just to test how other cells behave if one cell content has more than one line, since the first two examples do not use the native `<table>`.  See the differences in example 1 and 2? No? (Take a look how in example 2 the left cell did not expanded in height?)

Comment: @DaniSpringer why is `.cell` defined in CSS? ...so that you can style it and set the needed `width` thought it's obvious. You don't need to use `.cell`, you can use `<div>` without a classs and target them using `.table > div`...

Comment: @DaniSpringer Sure there's a way. It's not that difficult if you know how to use JS or jQuery.

Comment: @dani That's just an **example of content** to show in the demos the related differences and possible issues more visible... Who's forcing you to use the line break? Have you tried to play with the demos and remove the line break? Please - I gave you really lots of super-cool examples, now it's on you to explore and play.

Comment: @Dani, to play with my examples the easiest way to see immediately the result, use http://jsbin.com. Paste my code examples in the needed HTML / CSS tabs > see the result > play!

Comment: @DaniSpringer remove the .cell styles > see what happens, remove `width` > see what happens. Explore and have a nice time! Happy coding.

Answer (score -1):

```
table {
   empty-cells: hide;      
}
```