# Forcing table cell onto new row

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a standard table in which the cells appear left-to-right in the same row, but I'd like to force the third cell to appear on a new line. Is there a CSS tweak that can do this?

```
<table><tr>
<td class="col-1">One</td>
<td class="col-2">Two</td>
<td class="col-3">Three</td>
<td class="col-4">Four</td>
</tr></table>
```

This displays as: One Two Three Four

Can I force the third column to display on a new row thus:

```
One Two
Three Four
```

Comment: Show us your CSS, please

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just make it a new row?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33202614/how-to-easily-add-remove-cells-from-a-table-shifting-existent-cells

Comment: I can't make a new row because the HTML is for a responsive page, so it has to work before the media query kicks in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly sure why you wouldn't just make it a new row, but I suppose if you *had* to use CSS, you could do something like this:

```
table tr td {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jz6mypvw/)

Answer (score 0):

You can make a new row, by wrapping around your `td` with a `tr` as below

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="col-1">One</td>
    <td class="col-2">Two</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="col-3">Three</td>
    <td class="col-4">Four</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately my HTML is fixed