# Amount of table columns based on width of display

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am designing a website and on desktop I have a 2 column table, however on mobile the table does not look as good. Is it possible to determine the amount of table columns based on the screen width?

Desktop:

```
Cell 1     Cell 2
Cell 3     Cell 4
```

Mobile:

```
Cell 1
Cell 2
Cell 3
Cell 4
```

Comment: I did not post this as an answer because it is not the easiest solution for just adjusting your table, but if you have more things that should be different from the desktop version a good alternative is to use a redirect to a mobile version of your page if a mobile user agent is detected. Happy Coding ;-)

Answer (score 2):

It can be done by applying `display:flex` to your `tr` and adjusting the `td` size in a [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

```css
table{width:100%;}
tr { 
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width:100%;
}
td {
  width: 50%;
  border:1px solid blue;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
@media screen and (max-width:400px) {
  td{width:100%;}
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>col 1</td>
    <td>col 2</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>col 3</td>
    <td>col 4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You can find a functional example [here](http://codepen.io/BriceShatzer/pen/OWgmay)

Comment: I debated including the code from the codepen within the answer, and ultimately decided against it because I felt that since the viewport in the stack overflow snippet isn't adjustable, it wouldn't serve much purpose from a demonstration standpoint. That being said, your point about the possibility of the external link not working is fair, so I've updated it.

Comment: The answer seems more complete now. Going to remove my original comment and give your answer an upvote, nice one.

Answer (score 0):

I've answered a similar question here: [Forcing table cell onto new row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40568537/forcing-table-cell-onto-new-row)

Quite simply, what you're trying to do here is to make a table *not* behave as a table, which is interesting implementation. That being said, you could do something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/jz6mypvw/1/

Using `@media` queries, you can force your table to split into rows as the window gets smaller. The example below will be 2x2 when the screen width is `< 800px`, and finally one single column when the size is `< 500px`.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    table tr td {
        display: block;
        width: 50%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        float: left;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    table tr td {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="col-1">One</td>
        <td class="col-2">Two</td>
        <td class="col-3">Three</td>
        <td class="col-4">Four</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```